# Does "intends but to X" mean "intends something other than X"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> He intends but to help.

Does the above sentence mean:

> He intends anything but to/other than to help.

Comment: This is an archaic usage of 'but' meaning 'only': He intends only to help / He only wants to help.

Comment: It means he only intends to help. E.g., "I have but four dollars." means "I have only four dollars."

Comment: It might help to think of it as *He intends [to do nothing else] but to help.* Or in @jlovegren's example, *I have [nothing] but four dollars.*

Answer (score 3):

Without the word ***but***, the sentence...

> *He intends to help [her].*

...is a simple assertion of the fact of him having this intention. But as in this very sentence, including the word ***but*** implies ***contrast / refutation*** (in my example here, calling attention to the contrast between including or not including that extra word, refuting the possibility that it makes no difference). Thus, in OP's example,...

> *He intends but to help her.*

...refutes the *contextually implied* possibility that he “intends something other than helping” (i.e. - the *only* thing he intends to do is help; he has no other "hidden agenda").

In practice, OP's example is only likely to occur in contexts where she has already rejected his offer of help. Only the full context can establish whether this was because she thought he had ulterior motives, or (more likely, in practice) because she didn't think he was capable of helping anyway, regardless of his intentions.

---

Thus in the "more likely" scenario, the implied meaning would be something along the lines of *Don't react so negatively towards him. Although he may not **actually** be able to help you, **that and only that** is his intention*.

But you wouldn't often come across this construction today. As commented by [@Edwin](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/368631/does-intends-but-to-x-mean-intends-something-other-than-x?rq=1#comment861285_368631), it's at least dated, if not archaic. Much more common today would be...

> [*He's **only trying to help**.*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=only%20trying%20to%20help&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Conly%20trying%20to%20help%3B%2Cc0)